# Finally, you wake up from a coma

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, time

You can barely open your eyes when a doctor walks up to you:

> You are a lucky one. Not many people have survived an accident like this. Only a handful of neurosurgeons are able to perform such an intervention, which is why you were transferred here. It is still 2017 and after 237 days in a coma, life will
>   now slowly come back to normal. Welcome back.

[Doctor walks out of the hospital room]

While still trying to make sense of the situation, alone in the room, you take a glance at the clock on the wall. You swear you remember that the last time you checked before the accident was later on the same day.

**What was the date of the accident?**

Comment: A wall clock that shows the date?

Comment: not logical deduction, rather lateral thinking, pls change tag

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The date of the accident is

> March 11 2017

Explanation

> You look at the clock on the day of the accident, March 11 (11/3/2017) and wake up after being transferred to another country with another date format, 237 days later on November 3 (11/3/2017).

Comment: it is 234 days, not 237.

Comment: https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=10&m1=02&y1=2017&d2=2&m2=10&y2=2017

Comment: Oh then I guess that changes the answer

Comment: I'll think it's best if you change the answer to 11/3/17 -> 3/11/17. Don't want to steal the idea :) if it's not correct, then probably 12/2 -> 2/12, if you count the day you woke up.

Comment: That's right, updated now.